# Dijkstra's Algorithms and Negative Weights and Cycle

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, dijkstra

I study on Greedy Algorithm. summarize some important aspects about Dijkstra's Algorithms, that will be TRUE. i suspect about (4)  and (1), anyone could help me?

I) if all edges weight be negative, the Dijkstra's algorithm, works well.

II) if in graph we have a negative cycle, Dijkstra's get into a infinite loop and never end.

III) if a graph has a one edge with negative weight, but hasn't a negative cycle, the algorithm doesn't works well.

IV) if graph hasn't a negative cycle, the algorithms work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) only works on graphs with non-negative edges.  This is because it assumes that the first time a node is popped off the queue we have found the shortest path to that node and this is not necessarily true as soon as you have even one negative weight.

Therefore I is false, II is false (because the negative cycle may not necessarily be reachable), III is true, IV is false (it may still have a negative edge even without a negative cycle).

Comment: Suppose we have start->end (weight 1), start->mid (weight 2), mid->end (weight -3).  Dijkstra will say the shortest path is weight 1, but the actual answer is -1.  Therefore the algorithm can return the wrong value even in case III

Comment: i think we can add a constant to positive all edges and then use this algorithm? am i right?

Comment: This will only work if all routes to the end are of the same number of edges, otherwise you are giving more of a penalty to paths that use more edges.

Comment: What do u think about the last comment of @alexalv.

Comment: I am not sure I really understand his comment, but I still don't think I is true.  Suppose we have start->end (weight -1), start->mid (weight -2), mid->end (weight -3).  Dijkstra will found the answer -1, but the true answer is -5 so it has not worked correctly.

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean it has one edge with a negative weight, but not a negative cycle?  If so, this is false (see the counter example in my first comment)

Comment: Dear Peter, sorry, I have a typo.  if a graph has a one edge with negative weight, but hasn't a negative cycle, the algorithm doesn't work well? can I say it's True?

Comment: Correct, the algorithm may not return the correct answer in this case (as shown by the counterexample in my first comment).  So it is true that the algorithm doesn't work well.

Comment: I edit my typo in my question, would you please update your answer, thanks anyway. I vote +. thanks again.

Comment: Your comments are really useful in understanding how the algorithm works. Maybe you could merge them in your (already complete) answer :)

Comment: Dear @PeterdeRivaz, would you please say, why didn't correct your answer of edited part of my question?

Comment: Dear @PeterdeRivaz, if the negative edge is connected to start vertex, is it true again ?

Comment: I suppose that would work (unless there was a negative cycle), but in general I would advise to use a different algorithm if you have negative weights if at all possible so you can be sure of correct results even if the graph changes in the future.

Comment: so the III section may be true or maybe false? am I right? thanks for your kindly comments and lot's of effort to help me

Comment: In my opinion an algorithm that only works for certain inputs is not working well, but this is more a question of English usage than an algorithm question...

Answer (score 0):

If I remember it correctly Dijkstra's algorithm (at least the classic version of it) has a built in assumption that all weights in a graph are non-negative. So we have no guarantee that it will work correctly if we have negative edges in our graph.

I) In the first case we will most likely get a longest possible chain of edges with highest absolute values of weights as the shortest path, technically this will be the correct shortest path. (I assume the graph has no negative cycles)

II) False as negative cycle may be unreachable (as Peter de Rivaz [correctly said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587924/dijkstras-algorithms-and-negative-weights-and-cycle/28588497#28588497))

III-IV) I assume that the 3rd paragraph is about graph having one edge with negative *weight*, but hasn't a negative cycle. In this case there is a possibility of algorithm stucking in a loop, because it can find a cycle with a negative-weight edge that will seem to an algorithm as a good path prolongation beacuse at some point in algorithm we decide on the next step on the weight of one edge. The negative one will always be the first choice no doubt, so even with a non-negative cycle we getting a possibility of infinite looping.

Comment: I) is partially true, if we won't get into a loop (I guess this only possible if all the possible cycles in a given graph is unreachable) the Dijkstra's algorithm will return the longest possible with largest-absolute-value negative weights of edges. Technically it will be the shortest path (because it weights less than any other path).